# Something like debugDumpParams in pdo settable to a string

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to create a useful email to myself on pdo mysql errors, I am looking at "debugDumpParams", but sadly for some reason it just dumps the info right on the screen, you need to use output control functions to set it to a string which i don't quite understand.

Is there anything like that, that is settable to a string easily?

Answer (score 12):

The `debugDumpParams()` method writes to standard output. You can use an [output buffer](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to capture standard output into a string. The following code works for me, based on one of the [comments to `imagepng()` in the online manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php#28775) :

```
function pdo_debugStrParams($stmt) {
  ob_start();
  $stmt->debugDumpParams();
  $r = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $r;
}

// omitted: connect to the database and prepare a statement
echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(pdo_debugStrParams($stmt)).'</pre>';
```